# How do I configure Jenkins to build with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

How do I tell Jenkins to use the system installed Maven?

[image]

[image]

Why is it asking for MAVEN_HOME and not M2_HOME? Why doesn't it show the current system Maven? When the build runs, it gives a BS error:

> Parsing POMs
>   ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
>   org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
>   [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:[1.5.13,2.0) in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10

It works when I log into the machine as `jenkins` user  and run `mvn compile` on the command line.

```
-bash-4.2$ env | grep -i maven
PATH=/usr/local/src/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
M2_HOME=/usr/local/src/apache-maven-3.6.0

-bash-4.2$ mvn compile
...
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Here is the screen shot from the job configuration page. `/job/Weekly%20Report/configure`

[image]

Comment: You have shown the System Configuration page.  Can you please post your job configuration?  The Job need to say that it is using the tool called "Maven" you have defined.

Comment: Jenkins is asking for MAVEN_HOME to know where maven resides. When get it, will know where M2_HOME is. So just set the MAVEN_HOME value in Jenkins and it will work.

Comment: @AndrewGray I added a screen shot from the job configuration page. It doesn't explicitly say 'Maven', it just assumes Maven and find the `pom.xml`. I entered the goals. @Evgeni I did fill in the path to Maven, but it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand that your Jenkins tool and `jenkins` user are two different concepts.

By default Jenkins tool doesn't know about your current system tools like Maven. That's why if you need to use system Maven, you need to add Maven configuration in **Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration** page, then uncheck `Install automatically` checkbox and enter `Name` and `MAVEN_HOME`:
[image]
This will allow Jenkins to know path of your system Maven tool (as Evgeni Enchev already said in comments, after that Jenkins will know where `M2_HOME` is).

Then, in your jobs you also need to choose the proper version of Maven (use the name that you configured previously):
[image]

And then you will be able to run your system Maven.

Note: for using Maven in Jenkins pipelines see [Pipeline Maven Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Maven+Plugin).

Comment: Well you saw from my screen shot that I _did_ have the path to Maven set. (Also 'Install automatically' is unchecked). That just doesn't work. In _your_ screen shot you have a list of Mavens, but I just added a screen shot from my job configuration and my version of Jenkins (2.162) does not have that list.

Comment: @Chloe, what's your job type?  Freestyle project or Maven project?  You will get different options for each.  I would also recommend you migrate to pipeline as it has many many benefits.

Comment: It is a Maven project type.

Comment: I provided the information for a `Invoke top-level Maven targets` step in freestyle jobs (this step is also available in `Pre steps` and `Post steps` section of Maven projects). For `Build` section of a Maven project `Maven Version` is only shown if you have more than one Maven installation configured.

Comment: In your case I would recommend two things: try to add `M2_HOME` variable into Jenkins Environment variables (**Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** -> **Global properties**) or to downgrade your version of Jenkins to more stable (as I see, you're using last Weekly release - try to use last LTS version: Jenkins 2.150.2).
Also, as @Andrew Gray already said, you can use pipeline instead of Maven project .